# How to prevent variable truncation of double/float in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, truncate

This is probably a simple answer but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it yet.
I have a javascript function that takes the mouse location and passes it to a asmx page so it can process it and convert the x and y to a lat/long. I do however need accuracy of the mouse location. For some reason when the web service gets to it, its truncated down to 0 decimal places and I get like a 49.0, 105.0. I need the exact position like 9.34536. 104.345367.

I have already tried `toPrecision()` but the javascript wont even execute if I do this

```
someMethod((e.pageX - posX).toPrecision(15), (e.pageY - posY).toPrecision(15));
```

Here is the code I am using

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function (e) {

            $(".someElement").hover(function (e) {
                var posX = $(this).position().left;
                var posY = $(this).position().top;
                someMethod((e.pageX - posX), (e.pageY - posY));
            });
        })

        function someMethod(xToUse, yToUse) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "aWebServiceURL.asmx/someMethod",
                type: 'POST',
                data: "x=" + xToUse + "&y=" + yToUse,
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function iGotData(response, data) {
                    var resultingJSON = JSON.stringify(response);
                    $('#<%= aLabelOnTheScreen.ClientID %>').text(resultingJSON);


                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
                    console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
                    console.log("Status: " + status);
                    console.log(xhr);

                },

                // code to run regardless of success or failure

                complete: function (xhr, status) {
                  //  alert("The request is complete!");

                }


            });


        };
</script>
```

in C# the method definition is:

```
   public void someMethod(float x, float y)
{
}
```

**Update:** It turns out that I am only getting truncation in Safari and Chrome. Firefox and IE are not.

Comment: `setPrecision()` isn't a JavaScript method. Maybe you meant `toPrecision()` or `toFixed()`? Although each of those will return a `string` value, not a rounded number.

Comment: ah yes sorry... I will fix the question

Comment: What does your `someMethod` method signature look like?

Comment: updated the question as well:    `public void getPrecinctData(float x, float y){}`

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to check that `$(this).position().left` and `$(this).position().top` contain the values you want? Those are generally (but not always) integer values to begin with.

Comment: Thanks @Cory... ill check it out.... I have used a similar method in the past and it returns a full float/double value.

Comment: I don't think `toPrecision` will really help because that will just change 1.345 to 1.34500000. JS-wise I cant see an issue - http://jsfiddle.net/e1msyuts/ so I assume its something in the ASMX parameter binding

Comment: Actually its pretty awesome!!! So in Safari and Chrome it truncates them, in IE and Firefox it gives me the exact ones.....